# What's the use of 'cb => cb(snapshot)' in this code?

Tags: javascript

What is the use of 'cb => cb(snapshot)' ？

```
    if (this._snapshotCallbacks.length > 0) {
            const snapshot = gl.canvas.toDataURL();
            this._snapshotCallbacks.forEach(cb => cb(snapshot));
            this._snapshotCallbacks = [];
    }

    requestSnapshot (callback) {
            this._snapshotCallbacks.push(callback);
    }
```

Comment: That's a lambda expression. It's a function without a name.

Comment: Presumably `this._snapshotCallbacks` will be an array of functions, that line of code is saying to call each one of those functions with `snapshot` as the (first) argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this._snapshotCallbacks.forEach(cb => cb(snapshot));
```

can be rewritten as

```
this._snapshotCallbacks.forEach(function (callback) {
   callback(snapshot)
});
```

i think it's clear when there is no arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

`this._snapshotCallbacks.forEach(cb => cb(snapshot));`

means there is a collection of callbacks and the code here invokes them one after each other.

`forEach` is a function that exists on the array prototype that will take a function as a parameter and invoke this function for each element in the collection. When the function is invoked, the element is passed as the sole argument to the function that `forEach` took `cb => cb(snapshot)` is an es6 shorthand function definition.

So in your example, `cb` is a callback thats then invoked with the `snapshot`.

Basically, this is the same idea in a forloop

```
var function1 = (msg) => { alert(msg);}
var function2 = (msg) => { alert(msg.toUpperCase());}

var functions = [function1, function2];
for(var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++){
  var fnToApply = functions[i];
  fnToApply("hello world");
}
```

in which an array of functions is invoked in a loop, and each function is designed ahead of time to know what it takes as a param